# Forcing a sensor to sleep on RaspberryPi

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, microcontroller

I am new to microprocessor programing and currently have a RGB sensor which reads an RGB value and increments a variable by an arbitrary number. I want the sensor to turn off for 0.3 seconds when I reach a certain value. Is there a way to do this or will I have to figure out a different way to throw out all the values the RGB sensor receives during that 0.3 second time span? I am writing in C.

Note: The sensor I am currently using is a TCS230.

Comment: Do you know what sensor you have`Have you read its technical specification and other reference material about the sensor? That should tell you what you need to do to turn of the sensor, or if its even possible.

Comment: http://www.pobot.org/IMG/pdf/tcs230_datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 1):

According to the datasheet pin #3 is Output Enable ('OE, active low).  So if you drive this pin high it should cut off the chip's output.

Or more to your question, it looks like if you drive pins S0 and S1 both low, it will place the chip in a "Power Down" state.

Whichever option you choose depends on what's more important.  Do you want quickest reaction time, or do you want to conserve power?  If you want the quickest reaction time, use 'OE.  There is a typical 100ns delay between asserting this signal and the chip responding.  The downside is the chip is still running during this whole time.  If you choose the Power Down state, then you will save energy vs the Output Enable option, but the photodiodes have a typical 100 microsecond "recovery from power down" delay.  Obviously that's a factor of 1000, and if you're doing time-critical work, probably not the best option.

Keep in mind, I have never used this chip in my life, just basing my answer a quick read of the datasheet.

Comment: Sorry I am not following that second to last sentence. How is it a factor of 1000 if its a 100 microsecond recovery from power down? Also when using OE, when the chip is running is it still picking up data?

Comment: @astroboyy I mean in terms of timing. 100 microseconds is 1000 times slower than 100 nanoseconds. That's the difference between powering down the chip or simply cutting off the output. When you power down the chip, you will save energy at the expense of chip response time. If you simply cut off the chip's output, you will gain faster chip response time at the expense of using more energy. There are always tradeoffs in engineering. So it depends on your application. Will your Pi be plugged in all the time or running on battery? Will your application be OK with a 100 microsecond delay

Comment: (cont) or is that too slow? These are questions that vary project to project. And yes, even if you turn off the output, the chip should still be collecting data or doing whatever it's doing... as far as I know given the 5 min I spent with the datasheet. As far as datasheets go, that one is short.. read it. It will tell you more than you ever wanted to know. Anytime you need to use this chip or that part, the first place to start is its datasheet.

Comment: @astroboyy btw I got those timing numbers from the last 2 rows of the table on page 4. The units are in the last column,, the parameters are in the first column. Each diode is listed in the remaining columns. You'll see there's a minimum, typical, and maximum sub-header for each diode. The recovery from power down and 'OE response only list "typical" times